# MYSQL: Update a column value from a substring in another column?

Tags: mysql, string, substring, varchar

I have the following `MYSQL` table:

```
Job | Applicant  | link_Id

1    job_blogs_123    ?

2    steve_jobs_445  ?
```

The link_Id column in my table is currenty null for all rows.

I want it to be the substring after the *last* `_` in the Applicant column. So in this case 123 and 445.

How can I write a query that will update all the rows in my table in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET link_Id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Applicant, '_', -1);
```